# How to take a screenshot of application using QTP?

Tags: qtp

I want to take a screen shot of application when error occurs & save it in a specific folder. Below code works but it doesnt take a screen shot of application, it takes a screen shot of QTP Code screen.

```
Function CaptureImage()
    Dim Date_Time
    Dim Myfile
    Date_Time=Now() 
    Myfile= Date_Time&".png"
    Myfile = Replace(Myfile,"/","-") 
    Myfile = Replace(Myfile,":","-")
    Myfile= "C:\"&Myfile 
    Desktop.CaptureBitmap Myfile, True
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for youtr reply, but I want to take this screen shot using qtp.
I have never used try catch in qtp.

Comment: I changed my title  after reading spoko's 1st comments. I added 'using qtp' in title to make it more specific. But my tag was qtp only I didnt change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
Dim ScreenName

  On Error Resume Next

  ScreenName = " "
  
  CurrentTime = "_Test_Case"&"_"& Day(Now)&"_"& Month(Now)&"_"& Year(Now)&"_"&

   Hour(Now)&"_"& Minute(Now)&"_"& Second(Now)

  ScreenShotName = "Name_of_the_Screen" &  CurrentTime & ".png"

  ScreenName ="Path where the Screenshot needs to be stored"&"\"&ScreenShotName

  Desktop.CaptureBitmap ScreenName,True
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what you are asking it to do - taking a screenshot of the desktop. If you want to take a screenshot of a specific application then just make sure the application is visible/top-most on the desktop.

If you need to do that in code you can try the `Activate` method on various top-level objects. For example:

```
Window("Notepad").Activate
```

If you have a Browser you need to activate, you could try something like:

```
hwnd = Browser("...").GetROProperty("hwnd")
Window("hwnd:=" & hwnd).Activate
```

...and then take a screenshot. Really though the application under test should already be in the foreground and active if QTP opened it and has been performing actions on it.

Comment: Thanks Xiaofu, My code is correct , problem was in speed. I am testing an application which is running on virtual machine. VM machine's speed is less as compare to QTP due which i was facing that issue.
Now issue has resolved . Thanks

Comment: Then please add your own answer, and accept it, so this question will stop popping up as "unanswered".